# Equivalent definition of continuous maps between two topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X, Y$ be  two topological spaces. Are the following equivalent?

(1) $f$ is a conituous map between $X$ and $Y$.

(2) If $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $X$ with limit $x$ ,then $(f(x_n))$ converges to $f(x)$ in $Y$.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Is every space a sequential space? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1) \to (2)$ always holds. $(2) \to (1)$ depends ($X$ has to be a [sequential space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) in order to prove it.)

Comment: Does there exist a concrete example satisfying (2) but (1) is not satisfied?

Comment: @mathbeginner Sure. Let $X=\Bbb R$ be the co-countable topolgy, $Y = \Bbb R$ in the usual topology, If $f(x)=x$, the identity, then $f$ obeys $(2)$ but is not continuous.

Comment: If  $U$ any open set containging x (in the sense of co-countable topology, there exists N such that $x_n\in U$ when $n\geq N$, but $x_n$ may not lie in the interval of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @mathbeginner no, every convergent sequence in $X$ is eventually constant.